# Apply an independent formula till the range of Dynamic Array Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

In DataSet1 the first two columns come from a `FILTER()` function in Excel.  The third column is a sum of corresponding row from Dataset2.

I want the "Total Nums" column also to be dynamic and extended for the number of rows in the filter function.  I tried

```
=IF(CHOOSECOLS(G4#,1)<>"",K4+L4,0)
```

However, that just adds K4 and L4 and repeats the same number for rest of the rows.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: With corresponding rows, do you mean that if the Subledger Amount "21,331.45" was the 1st row in its range, you want the 1st row in the Data Set 2 i.e. A243:B234 (start of the range you're filtering) -> S4:T5 **or** the same row that they're both on in Excel, i.e. A4:B4 -> S4:T4 ?

Answer (score 1):

`=LET(f,FILTER(S4:T28,A4:A28=$G$4),g,CHOOSECOLS(G4#,1),IF(g<>"",CHOOSECOLS(f,1)+CHOOSECOLS(f,2),0))`

This basically depends on what G4# is based on but would give you the other addition possibility.

For a visual:

[image]

Added P.b's result for comparison and to test his SEQUENCE out :)

Answer (score 0):

`=LET(s,SEQUENCE(ROWS(G4#),,ROW(G4#)),INDEX(K:K,s)+INDEX(L:L,s))`

This will create a sequence equal to the row numbers of `G4#` if we index column K and L with that sequence and use `+` as an operator, it will sum by row dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using `ROW()` function as well. That said `=ROW(G4#)-3` returns an array starting from `{1;..;last_row}` and expands/resizes automatically based on the adjacent array `G4#`.

[image]

---

Formula used in cell `I4`

```
=LET(α,ROW(G4#)-3,INDEX(K4:K18,α)+INDEX(L4:L18,α))
```

---

Also one another alternative way using `BYROW()` without `LAMBDA()` construct and this presently works with `MS365` for Beta Channel Users.

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(INDEX(K4:L18,ROW(G4#)-3,{1,2}),SUM)
```

---

Or,

```
=BYROW(CHOOSEROWS(K4:L18,SEQUENCE(ROWS(G4#))),SUM)
```

---